# Function call inside complex query

Tags: oracle, plsql

Recently someone gave me the query below to take the open price, and then find the next price which is > the open price.
This works perfectly.
Now of course, they are changing the specs on me.  Rather than using "open price", then want "price change percent", from previous day.
I have a function for that already, which I am listing the call below.....but I am not sure how to implement it into the query.  I'm hoping someone can help.

Original Query

```
SELECT MAX(price_date), MIN(open_price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY price_date DESC)
FROM price_history p, master_Table m 
WHERE p.ticker = m.ticker 
AND open_price > (SELECT MIN(open_price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY price_date DESC) 
                  FROM price_history@ p, master_table m 
                  WHERE p.ticker = m.ticker 
                    AND m.m_ticker = 'IBM') 
AND m.m_ticker ='IBM';
```

Call to Price Change Percent function:

```
PRICE_FUNCTIONS.NET_CHANGE('IBM', TRUNC(SYSDATE), 1, 'PCT')
```

Sample Data:

```
IBM 20170330    173.86
IBM 20170329    174.3
IBM 20170328    173.94
IBM 20170327    172.69
IBM 20170324    175.12
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line, no need to add `<BR>`

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @LandonStatis in addition to Juan's 2nd comment requesting more info, please also provide the code for the net_change function. Whilst it will be possible to incorporate the function in your query, it will be more performant to put the logic directly into the sql query (thus avoiding all the context switching required by calling out to the function).

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of more information from you, maybe this will give you some ideas as to how to proceed?

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 'IBM' ticker, to_date('30/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') price_date, 173.86 open_price FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'IBM' ticker, to_date('29/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') price_date, 174.3 open_price FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'IBM' ticker, to_date('28/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') price_date, 173.94 open_price FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'IBM' ticker, to_date('27/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') price_date, 173.69 open_price FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'IBM' ticker, to_date('24/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') price_date, 175.12 open_price FROM dual),
         interim AS (SELECT ticker,
                            price_date,
                            MAX(price_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker) max_price_date,
                            open_price,
                            LAG(price_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY price_date) prev_price_date,
                            LAG(open_price) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY price_date) prev_open_price
                     FROM   sample_data)
SELECT ticker,
       price_date,
       open_price,
       prev_price_date,
       ROUND(100 * (open_price - prev_open_price) / prev_open_price, 2) percentage_change_from_yday
FROM   interim
WHERE  price_date = max_price_date;

TICKER PRICE_DATE  OPEN_PRICE PREV_PRICE_DATE PERCENTAGE_CHANGE_FROM_YDAY
------ ----------- ---------- --------------- ---------------------------
IBM    30/03/2017      173.86 29/03/2017                            -0.25
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not thing this will work.    The query should actually return 3/29, 174.3....as it is the next next highest from 3/30.    But, that next highest could be anywhere.....even 3/12........

Comment: And that's exactly why we requested more info. If you can't work out how to amend my query to get the results you're after, you'll need to update your question to add in the extra info.